# Can I power a Raspberry Pi Zero and use the data connectors on a MicroUSB header at the same time?

Tags: power, pi-zero-w

Curious to see if this is possible as I have two USB data connections I want to use simultaneously on the Pi.

Comment: have you considered using a USB hub on the USB port? Probably far easier

Comment: One connector is power only. The other is power and data (connected in parallel with the power connector). You can power a zero through the data socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi Zero has only **ONE** USB port.

The power connector might use a microUSB connector but it has no data pins, only power pins.

You can power the Pi via either port (this is not true of normal Pi).

Comment: Correction, the Pi Zero W has two MicroUSB OTG ports

Comment: This is not true. One port is power only and has no data lines connected. All Raspberry Pi SoCs (except Pi 4) only have ONE USB 2.0 host. On most models there is an onboard USB-Hub that connects multiple ports and ethernet.