# Can the Raspberry Pi work with Ethernet using a USB-Ethernet power adapter?

Tags: ethernet, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, usb-power

I have a Google Chromecast Ultra power adapter which includes Ethernet. My thinking, this is a USB to Ethernet adapter that also provides 5V power.

Does this work with the Raspberry Pi Zero W to give it Ethernet? From my testing, yes, but I needed to use the USB-data port rather than USB-power.

As far as I know, **you *can* power the Raspberry Pi Zero W over the USB-data port with no problems, but I'm not exactly sure**. Could someone clarify?

https://store.google.com/us/product/chromecast_ethernet_adapter_gen_2

[image: Google Chromecast power adapter with Ethernet over USB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does work with power-over-ethernet adapters. I own quite a few adapters like this.

What happens is it creates a data connection for USB Ethernet using 2 USB pins and uses the other 2 USB pins for power. It seems strange to think of it like this, but these devices split power and Ethernet into 2 pieces.

If your device is compatible (which Raspberry Pi are), then you can receive Ethernet over USB *and* power through the same USB port. This is because the Raspberry Pi can also be powered from the data port.

It's nice having a single micro-USB into the Raspberry Pi and a single Ethernet cable going into the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The Ethernet ports on the Pi (and indeed almost ANY computer) are galvanically isolated so normally have no direct electrical connection to the Pi.

Ethernet **DOES NOT** provide any power.
Normally USB to Ethernet adapters require power FROM the USB port.

You can power the Raspberry Pi Zero over the USB-data port as it does not have any of the protection methods included in some other models. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114381/8697

So assuming the USB to Ethernet adapter you are using PROVIDES power it would work, but as what you are proposing seems to have no source of power it is unlikely.

Comment: I couldn't find a picture of the gen1 device that I have, but this is a power brick with Ethernet and a micro USB wire going to your Raspberry Pi. It's power, Ethernet, and a USB to Ethernet adapter all in one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to PoE (Power over Ethernet) the Raspberry Pi, you'll need a [PoE Hat](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-hat/) to power the the Raspberry. However you'll need to ensure the other end of the ethernet cable is connected to a PoE port too (ie PoE switch).